# Source Tree not seeing a visual indication that I need to push

Tags: mercurial, sourcetree

On computer A) I can see that the tip of my working copy recently committed. There was no indication that I needed to push, and yet it turned out that I did need to push.

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: I forgot to take a screen grab of the push and pull icons , but I would have noticed if they were out of the ordinary.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to define a 'default' remote repository? (Ask with `hg paths`)